# Поменять src у background

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите,как мне обратиться ко всем div у которых установлен background-image и поменять им src
Примерно должно быть так

```
     $('селектор div у которых background-image ').each(function () {
     var scr= получить src div
     var tarr = src.split('/');
     nsrc = tarr[tarr.length - 1];

 и установить уже обрезанный url


  )};
```

заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-image') !== 'none';
}).attr('src', 'my-src');
```

Comment: Неа,не заменяет на "mysrc"

Comment: Тебе точно нужно заменить src?  [Все работает url-test](https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=RXtofDVIMraguLhoe8m2lwadTyPUXV)

Comment: Оплошался ,перепутал url с src ,мне нужно url заменить

Comment: Ну используй не attr а это: [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Да,получилось,спасибо!